# Can vertex alpha be set for a surface shader appdata input?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, cg

My shader does some math to determine vertex alpha, so I've got a function to do that before the data gets passed into my surf function.

```
    #pragma surface surf Standard alpha
    #pragma target 3.0

    struct Input
    {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
        float tranparency;
    };

    void foo(inout appdata_full v, out Input o) {
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
        float someAlpha;
        [...some maths to create someAlpha value...]
        v.color.a = someAlpha;
        o.transparency = v.color.a;
    }

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;

    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
    {
        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
```

Then when I use Input IN I want someAlpha to be reflected when the alpha is set:

```
o.Alpha = c.a; //Can I do c.a * IN.transparency ?
```

Currently, absolutely nothing happens.  How can I use the alpha value I want in surf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can add a `COLOR` semantic to your `Input` object:

```
struct Input {
    float4 uv_MainTex;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    };
```

Then assign to it in `foo` (although this may not be necessary if you have `#pragma surface surf`):

```
void foo(inout appdata_full v, out Input o) {
    UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
    float someAlpha;
    [...some maths to create someAlpha value...]
    v.color.a = someAlpha;

    o.color = v.color;
}
```

Then use it in `surf`:

```
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
{
    fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
    fixed4 vertexColor = IN.color;
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;
    o.Metallic = _Metallic;
    o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
    o.Alpha = vertexColor.a * c.a; 
}
```

Finally, tell Unity to use `foo` as a vertex shader before the surface shader by changing `#pragma surface surf Standard alpha` to:

```
#pragma surface surf Standard alpha vertex:foo
```

Comment: I tried this out and didn't get any result.  I even tried setting o.vertColor = 0; but that value doesn't seem to have any effect when o.Alpha is set to vertexColor.a (or IN.vertColor.a) in the surf function.

Comment: I've added the pragma. It doesn't seem like variable name on `float4 var : COLOR` is the issue, according to Input struct docs.

Comment: @Nol Thanks for including that information now. Seems like it's not using your vertex shader at all. Change your `#pragma surface surf Standard alpha` to `#pragma surface surf Standard alpha vertex:vert`

Comment: Brilliant!  I never noticed, I just needed to define my `foo` as a vertex shader.  It's not working quite the same as my non-surface shader version, but now it's just math.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah `foo` not `vert`. glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm what is written in the approved answer. I ran a few tests and had a look at the generated code.

The surface shader will always set the color in vertex program to:

```
o.color = v.color;
```

No matter what it actuall says. So if you have:

```
struct Input {
    fixed4 color : COLOR;
};

void vert(inout appdata v, out Input o) {
    o.color = v.color * fixed4(2,1,1,1);
}
```

Unity will generate this:

```
v2f_surf vert_surf (appdata v) {
  UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
  v2f_surf o;
  [...]
  Input customInputData;
  vert (v, customInputData);
  [...]
  o.color = v.color;
  [...]
}
```

So what you can do, is to put your code in the surf function instead:

```
float4 vertexColor = IN.color * fixed4(2,1,1,1);
```